# How to read DDR4 SPD with ee1004 driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

I'm trying to read DDR4 RAM SPD data with the new ee1004 driver. I thought that after `modprobe ee1004` I would be able to read data from `/sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ee1004`, however thats not the case (no devices appeared there). Am I missing something?

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 with Kernel 5.0.0-13. Contents of ee1004 directory in sysfs is:

```
user@ryzen:/sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ee1004$ ls -l
celkom 0
--w------- 1 root root 4096 apr 28 21:33 bind
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 apr 28 21:33 module -> ../../../../module/ee1004
--w------- 1 root root 4096 apr 28 21:33 uevent
--w------- 1 root root 4096 apr 28 21:33 unbind
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find solution thanks to RafDouglas.

The trick is to manually set i2c addresses to ee1004 driver. Follow these instructions https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-i2c/msg32331.html (start at "*First you must find out the i2c bus number of your motherboard's SMBus ...*")

Answer (score 3):

Welcome, user22600!

You can try using decode-dimms, which supports the [ee1004 driver](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools/+/refs/heads/master/eeprom/decode-dimms):

```
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
sudo modprobe eeprom
sudo modprobe ee1004
decode-dimms|grep -A6 SPD
```

looking at your specific listing of /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ee1004, however, I am not sure the modules are detected correctly by the kernel, which is a pre-requisite of any tool.

After loading the ee1004 module, and verifying no errors are returned, I would suggest to check dmesg outputs:

sudo dmesg

```
sudo dmesg -c
sudo modprobe eeprom
sudo modprobe ee1004
sudo dmesg
```

Comment: Hello @RafDouglas, unfortunatelly it did solved my problem. There are no messages in dmesg after loading ee1004. Decode-dimms is also throwing error: `No EEPROM found, the kernel probably does not support your hardware.`

Is there any other way how to check whether ee1004 is working? Or is this kernel bug or ee1004 bug?

Comment: what do you get from
`ls -la /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ee1004/module/`
?

Comment: this: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ZwgSmJXw3h/

Comment: I edited the previous answer, adding
`sudo modprobe eeprom`
which your system might have missed. 

Just to ask the obvious: are you positive your PC has DDR4 memory modules mounted? 

if you issue:

  `modprobe i2c-dev`
  `i2cdetect $(i2cdetect -l | grep smbus|tr " \t" '--'|cut -d'-' -f2) 0x50 0x57`

are there addresses in use in the 0x50-0x55 range?

Comment: Please see also the original post of the decode-dimms developer: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-i2c/msg32331.html

Comment: RafDouglas, thank you! I was able to get it working with your help. With eeprom enabled (then didn't matter whether ee1004 was enabled), I was able to read first 256 bytes from SPD. With i2cdetect there was some addreses used when eeprom was enabled(but your command did not work beacuse `i2cdetect -l | grep smbus` returned multiple devices) . The trick was to manually set addresses to ee1004 driver with `# echo ee1004 [address] > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-[bus_number]/new_device`. Then I was able to read full 512 bytes.
For others: follow  spinics.net/lists/linux-i2c/msg32331.html

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :)